# Frequent view switching causes lagg

Tags: iphone, xcode, performance

I have made an app that runs quite smoothly. However, every time I switch views it gets more laggy and eventually (after about 5 times of switching) it shows an incredible amount of lagg. The view switching seems to cause it. What can I do to prevent it? Is is because I dont switch views correctly, or maybe ARC?

Note: I use IB to switch views (ctrl + click -> draw a line and then select modal).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Allocations tool in Instruments, verify that you are properly managing memory.

Two Considerations

1. If you are creating a new instance of a view each time you
   switch, make sure you are properly releasing the old view (and all
   objects associated with it).
2. A better approach, if you are just
   changing the data in the view, rather than showing a totally
   different view, use a single instance of the view, and just update
   it with the new data.

Either way, sounds like your problem is that you are continually allocating new instances of the view (and the objects that go with it) and not properly releasing the out of date copies.

Allocations in Instruments will tell you exactly how many copies are in memory.  You should look to see that when you switch views, the number of instances does not continually increase.

Comment: Thanks, but for now I just drag a line in IB. I don't have any code for releasing the view and the objects associated with it (I use ARC). What can I do to prevent the lagg? Which code should I use or shoudn't I use IB for the view switching? I have tried releasing the objects at "dealloc", but ARC forbids it...